# How do you render a View with arguments using a Computed Field?

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have a computed field and i want to output a View's - block display with arguments passed into it. Can someone provide me with an example code of how to output a view with arguments?

thanks!

Comment: actually i just realized that you cannot do this as a computed field is mainly used for storing data and since a views render would be dynamic, it would not work. a computed field only fires when you save your node.

Comment: There are 2 ways for computed fields - stored and dynamic. You just don't want to store it.

Comment: your correct... there is a check box to make the field into a dynamic field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The long way:**

```
$args = array(ARGUMENTS);
$view = views_get_view('VIEWNAME');
print $view->preview('block_1', $args);
```

**The short way:**

```
print views_embed_view('my_view', 'block_1', $arg1, $arg2);
```

Also keep in mind since this is dynamic data, you will need to uncheck the checkbox on the field settings page or else it will try to store the data thats generated upon saving the node.